# Should we keep stretching the meaning of [stretch]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-cleanup-request

This is about [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch). It's the code name of the current stable Debian release, and it's also a tag on the main site.

*Most* of the usage seems to be about [debian-stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-stretch) -- there are 19 questions tagged [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch), of which 10 are tagged [debian](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian) [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch) and 6 are tagged [linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch), only one of the latter not also being tagged [debian](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian). However, there is at least one question thrown into the mix that appears to have to do with graphical artefacts rather than Debian.

I strongly suspect that most of the questions tagged [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch) can be retagged [debian-stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-stretch) with next to or no ill effects. That would also go in line with [debian-lenny](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-lenny), [debian-squeeze](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-squeeze), [debian-wheezy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-wheezy) and [debian-jessie](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-jessie).

I propose that [stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stretch) be replaced by [debian-stretch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/debian-stretch) where the question is about the Debian release, and that the few remaining questions are retagged as appropriate.

Comment: I agree with this proposal.

Comment: Question here is really retag or synonomise?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good point. It looks at a glance like [wheezy] is a synonym, but [squeeze] is not, and [lenny] and [jessie] don't exist. So it's a bit of a mess all around with Debian release codename tags.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Judging from the other release specific tags there probably won't be much to gain from synonymisation. On the other hand, the other tags only have about 200 questions, so retagging is probably not going to be a big deal. Also the tag will be somewhat clearer in its meaning. The one question where debian or linux is not tagged is about resizing windows in Windows.

Comment: On UL we obliterated them.

Comment: Looks like a half dozen non debian-stretch questions about assorted random graphics things that predate the releases availability; still no reason not to retag them and rename the tag for whats left.